# I am getting a function undefined error with my javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, date

I'm trying to calculate the age of a person based on an 8 digit input. When I try to run the code it says `TypeError` undefined is not a function..

```
var calcAge = function (dob) {

    var age,

        mm = dob.substring(0, 2),
        dd = dob.substring(2, 4),
        yyyy = dob.substring(4, 8),
        d = new Date(),
        currentDay = d.getDay,
        currentMonth = (d.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? "0" + (d.getMonth() + 1) : d.getMonth() + 1,
        currentYear = d.getFullYear;


        if (parseInt("" + mm + dd) >= parseInt("" + currentMonth + currentDay)) {
            age = currentYear - yyyy;
        } else {
            age = (currentYear - yyyy) - 1;
        };

        return age;
};
```

Comment: what does your function call look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

d.getDay() and  d.getFullYear() are functions not string values,you were using getDay() which returns the dayofweek instead of getDate() and your final test was a little off.

```
var calcAge = function (dob) {
var age,
    mm = dob.substring(0, 2),
    dd = dob.substring(2, 4),
    yyyy = dob.substring(4, 8),
    d = new Date(),
    currentDay = d.getDate(),
    currentMonth = (d.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? "0" + (d.getMonth() + 1) : d.getMonth() + 1,
    currentYear = d.getFullYear();
    if (parseInt("" + mm + dd) <= parseInt("" + currentMonth + currentDay)) {
        age = currentYear - yyyy;
    } else {
        age = (currentYear - yyyy) - 1;
    };
    return age || false;
};
```

using these tests it seems correct now 
    calcAge('02191964');//returns 51
    calcAge('02201964');// 51
    calcAge('02211964');//50

Comment: that is a chained var statement. it assigns all the vars to be local to the new window method calcAge.
var age;
var mm = dob.substring(0, 2);
var dd = dob.substring(2, 4);
means the same thing.
window.calcAge.mm or mm will return undefined because they are out of scope outside the method.

Comment: This worked for the most part. The ternary was completely irrelevant it turns out. Thanks for the help though guys

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing in the dob parameter as 8 integers your substring calls will return the error you are seeing.